# How do i display data by ID from mysql database

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

| id | product_title | product_desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Iphone 12 | this is iPhone 12 |
| 1001 | Iphone 11 | this is iPhone 11 |
| 1002 | Iphone X | this is iPhone X |
| 1003 | Iphone 8 | this is iPhone 8 |
| 1004 | Iphone 7 | this is iPhone 7 |

I have a table called **products** that looks something like the table above. I displayed all the products on my page. But now I want to use bootstrap modal to display the product description when I clicked on the name of that particular product.( ***Exp: I click on the product name of iPhone 12 on my page. A boostrap modal will be displayed to show me the description of iPhone 12.*** )

My question is how can I display the description of that particular product that I click on? Now I am having an output of all the descriptions of the products in my modal.

This is the codes where I use to display the products

```
<div class="row form-group" id="myDIV">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_status = 1 ORDER BY product_created DESC LIMIT 6";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
      echo '
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
        </div>
      ';
    } else {

      while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 form-group" style="padding: 0 8px 0 8px;">
        <div class="product-wrapper">
          <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="product-title" style="min-height: 39px;">
              <span class="float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productdesc1">
              <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
              </span>
              </h5>
            <a href="product.php?cid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-block addtocart text-center" style="text-decoration: none">View More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php 
        }
      } 
    ?>
  </div>
```

These are the codes that I use for my bootstrap modals

```
    <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="productdesc1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="float-right mb-3">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:#ed1c25;">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <?php
    $sql = "SELECT product_desc FROM products";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
      echo '
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
        </div>
      ';
    } else {

      while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
    <div class="mb-3">
       <h5 class="product-title">Description</h5>
        <p><?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
      }
          } 
        ?>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i will show you make simple with jquery

first i add onlick ShowModalProduct() at your `<a>` and will look like this

`<a href="#" onclick="ShowModalProduct(<?=$row['id'];?>)" class="btn btn-block addtocart text-center" style="text-decoration: none">View More</a>`

`<?=$row['id'];?>` its from foreach the data and will be parameter for show `product_desc` at javascript code

and then at the modal i will give id at each `<div>`

```
<div class="mb-3 hidden" id="products_<?=$row['id'];?>">
   <h5 class="product-title">Description</h5>
      <p><?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></p>
</div>
```

and i use this jquery library 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and add the script the function `ShowModalProduct()` will look like this, when the function fired, it will remove class hidden and add class show-desc

```
function ShowModalProduct(id){
    $('#products_'+id).removeClass('hidden');
    $('#products_'+id).addClass('show-desc');
    $('#productdesc1').modal('toggle');
}
```

i forget to mention i add 2 class style to show/hide the div section, and when foreach the product desc first i add class hidden like this `<div class="mb-3 hidden" id="products_<?=$row['id'];?>">` and include `id` at the sql (`SELECT id,product_desc FROM products`)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }
    .show-desc{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

and i add onclick `CloseModal()` at button close modal like this

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal();" style="color:#ed1c25;">&times;</button>
```

and then add the function script like this

```
function CloseModal(){
   $(".show-desc").each(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#"+id).removeClass('show-desc');
       $("#"+id).addClass('hidden');
    });
     $('#productdesc1').modal('hide');
 }
```

so when the modal close, it will change all class `show-desc` to class `hidden` so when you showing another modal, the previous div not showing again

full code will look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
        .show-desc{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="row form-group" id="myDIV">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_status = 1 ORDER BY product_created DESC LIMIT 6";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);

            if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
              echo '
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
                </div>
              ';
            } else {

              while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            ?>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 form-group" style="padding: 0 8px 0 8px;">
                <div class="product-wrapper">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="product-title" style="min-height: 39px;">
                      <span class="float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productdesc1">
                      <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
                      </span>
                      </h5>
                    <a href="#" onclick="ShowModalProduct(<?=$row['id'];?>)" class="btn btn-block addtocart text-center" style="text-decoration: none">View More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php 
                }
              } 
            ?>
        </div>  

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="productdesc1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="float-right mb-3">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal();" style="color:#ed1c25;">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                        <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT id,product_desc FROM products";
                            $query = $conn->query($sql);

                            if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
                              echo '
                                <div class="col-12">
                                  <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
                                </div>
                              ';
                            } else {

                              while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

                            ?>
                            <div class="mb-3 hidden" id="products_<?=$row['id'];?>">
                               <h5 class="product-title">Description</h5>
                                <p><?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                              }
                          } 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function ShowModalProduct(id){
                    $('#products_'+id).removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#products_'+id).addClass('show-desc');
                    $('#productdesc1').modal('toggle');
                }

                function CloseModal(){
                    $(".show-desc").each(function(){
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        $("#"+id).removeClass('show-desc');
                        $("#"+id).addClass('hidden');
                    });
                    $('#productdesc1').modal('hide');
                }
            </script>
                
    </body>
</html>
```

if use ajax, change the function at script like this

```
function ShowModalProduct(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetProduct.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {'id':id}, 
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            if(response==null){
                alert('Data Not Found');
            }else{
                data =  response;
                $('#desc-product').html(data.product_desc);
                $('#productdesc1').modal('toggle');
            }
        }
    });
}

function CloseModal(){
    $('#productdesc1').modal('hide');
}
```

and create new php file GetProduct.php for get detail product

```
<?php 
    $id_product = $_GET['id'];

     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test"); //your config connection
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_status = 1 and id='".$id_product."' ";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     $row =  $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

full code at main file will like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <!--    
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
        .show-desc{
            display: block;
        }
    </style> 
    -->
    <body>
        <div class="row form-group" id="myDIV">
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test"); //your config connection
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_status = 1 ORDER BY product_created DESC LIMIT 6";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);

            if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
              echo '
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
                </div>
              ';
            } else {

              while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            ?>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 form-group" style="padding: 0 8px 0 8px;">
                <div class="product-wrapper">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="product-title" style="min-height: 39px;">
                      <span class="float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productdesc1">
                      <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
                      </span>
                      </h5>
                    <a href="#" onclick="ShowModalProduct(<?=$row['id'];?>)" class="btn btn-block addtocart text-center" style="text-decoration: none">View More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php 
                }
              } 
            ?>
        </div>  

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="productdesc1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="float-right mb-3">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal();" style="color:#ed1c25;">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                               <h5 class="product-title">Description</h5>
                                <p id="desc-product"></p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function ShowModalProduct(id){
                     $.ajax({
                        url: 'GetProduct.php',
                        type: 'get',
                        data: {'id':id}, 
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response==null){
                                alert('Data Not Found');
                            }else{
                                data =  response;
                                $('#desc-product').html(data.product_desc);
                                $('#productdesc1').modal('toggle');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                function CloseModal(){
                    $('#productdesc1').modal('hide');
                }
            </script>
                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can learn ajax for more flexible to get data

Comment: do you mean create another PHP files for the query to show the description and called it using AJAX?

Comment: you can get data with format json, and set the data inside the div, so you dont need foreach the data at modal first, just get the data with ajax, and set data into the div

Comment: do you mind show me the example of demo codes for the explanation you made above? thank you so much!  :)

Comment: try learn from this https://salitha94.blogspot.com/2018/01/view-data-in-bootstrap-modal-using-ajax-jquery-and-php.html

Comment: okay thank you so much for providing the information!

Comment: just learn first, if you get struggle just create new question with proper information

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways:

1. Set the modal in the item list, inside the **`foreach`** block, and but the item description inside the modal, but don't forget to change modal ID regarding the toggle button id.
2. Call an **`onclick`** event when user clicks on item name, the action accociated with this event calls ajax request to get element by ID from database, when the request success, set the retrieved data inside a modal and make it visible.